# How to define type of props of SVGElement in React + TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, eslint

I am going to define a svg element as a react component like this.

```
import React from 'react';

const CheckMark = ({
  className = 'w-4 h-4',
  ...other,
}: React.SVGProps<SVGElement>) => (
  <path
    className={className}
    d="..."
    {...other}
  />
);

export default CheckMark;
```

However, I am getting an eslint error:

'className' is missing in props validation (eslint-react/prop-types)

How can I resolve this error?

It's the content of eslintrc

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "overrides": [],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "comma-dangle": [
      "error",
      {
        "arrays": "only-multiline",
        "objects": "only-multiline",
        "imports": "only-multiline",
        "exports": "only-multiline",
        "functions": "only-multiline"
      }
    ],
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to use it like this.

```
<svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <CheckMark width="16" height="16" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

To define the type of props for an SVG element in React with TypeScript

```
import React from 'react';
interface Props {
    className: string,
}
const CheckMark = ({
  className = 'w-4 h-4',
}: Props) => (
  <path
    className={className}
    d="..."
  />
);
export default CheckMark;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I made a mistake when I post the problem. I want to enable other all props of path element.